# Array Permutations/Combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

I’m trying to find the best way to check if a String is either

1. Equal to the array value at a single index.
2. Equal to a permutation of the array
3. Equal to any combination of values.
    
   3.1 This can include a combination of array values with spaces between words.
    
   3.2 This can include a combination of array values without spaces between words.
4. **THE ARRAY VALUES THEMSELVES WILL NOT HAVE SPACES OR SPECIAL CHARACTERS**
5. Each array value will be unique. There are no duplicate values.
6. There will never be more than two words in the string.
7. There will never be special characters in the string, but there can be spaces.

Any ideas?

Example data:

```
var stringExample = "application Name";

var arrayExample = ['app', 'application', 'name'];
```

Psuedo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayExample.length; i++) {
     if (stringExample.toLower() == arrayExample[i]) {
          return true;
     } elseif (stringExample.toLower() == "Any Combination of array values with spaces or
                       without spaces in between") { return true };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently a word in the input string could need a concatenation of two or more array elements to be considered a match. This is probably the most tricky part of the requirement.

Secondly, it seems that once a word has matched with a (or combination of) array value(s), those array elements should not be used any more for yet another match.

I would suggest using a plain object to store the array values as properties. This will allow fast look-up, and removal (for meeting the second point above) can also be done quite efficiently. For implementing the first requirement I would stick with a brute force approach. Alternatively you could build a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), but you would need a huge input before you would get a benefit from it, so I will not propose that.

You can use recursion to find a solution for a smaller problem after you found a potential match for a (part of a) word.

Here is an EcmaScript 3 solution that implements those ideas:

```js
function match(str, arr) {
    var words = str.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
    var keys = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) keys[arr[i].toLowerCase()] = 1;

    function recur(i) {
        if (i >= words.length) return true;
        var word = words[i];
        if (keys[word]) { // Try full match first - relatively fast operation
            keys[word] = 0;
            if (recur(i+1)) return true;
            keys[word] = 1; // backtrack: restore key
        } else { // Try partial match - relatively slow operation
            for (var key in keys) {
                if (!keys[key] || word.slice(0, key.length) !== key) continue;
                keys[word] = 0;
                words[i] = word.slice(key.length);
                if (recur(i)) return true;
                words[i] = word; // backtrack: restore word
                keys[word] = 1; // backtrack: restore key
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return recur(0);
}

var str = "application Name";
var arr = ['nam', 'me', 'applica', 'app', 'lication', 'na'];
console.log(match(str, arr));
```

Comment: I’ll implement and test when I get back, but this looks really good. Thank you. And thanks for the patience and lesson in Stack questions, I’ve learned a lot today.

Answer (score 0):

So matching the complete string and it's parts if they are split by a space is quite easy:

```js
var stringExample = "application Name";
var example2 = "app King";
var example3 = "application";
var example4 = "some random string";
var arrayExample = ['app', 'application', 'name'];

function findMatch(string, array){
  var a1 = string.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  var match = false;
  // create array simply to check for each string part if it is in the array
  var matches  = [];
  for(var j = 0; j < a1.length; j++){
    matches.push(false);
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    // Checking for complete Match
    if(string.toLowerCase() === array[i].toLowerCase()){
      match = true;
      break;
    }
    // Checking for partly matches
    for(var j = 0; j < a1.length; j++){
      if(a1[j] === array[i].toLowerCase()){
        matches[j] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  // if all parts of the string have a match, return true
  if(matches.every(function(b){return b === true;})){
    match = true;
  }
  return match;
}

console.log(stringExample + " does match: " + findMatch(stringExample, arrayExample));
console.log(example2 + " does match: " + findMatch(example2, arrayExample));
console.log(example3 + " does match: " + findMatch(example3, arrayExample));
console.log(example4 + " does match: " + findMatch(example4, arrayExample));
```